# FullCalendar view freeze after viewRender

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asynchronous, fullcalendar

I'm having quite an issue here, I'm trying to load event while changing view using a sync point. Changing the sync point works great, I can also send and receiver the informations. But the calendar still freeze, I have to change a few month before it start to works again. I can then come back to the previous month.
I'm using AngularJS to load the event, and a `$q` to load data before the request:

```
$q(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve(beforeSendStatus());
}).then(function() {
  EventService.get({
    start: moment(start).format("DD-MM-YYYY"),
    end: moment(end).format("DD-MM-YYYY"),
    format: 'FC',
    onlyMe: false
  }).then(function(data) {
    $('.status').find('i').removeClass("fa-spin fa-circle-o-notch").addClass('fa-check');

    Calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvents', data.data);
    eventLenghtCalc(view, 325);
  }, function(error) {
    $('.status').find('i').removeClass("fa-spin fa-circle-o-notch").addClass('fa-close').css({
      'color': 'red'
    });
    toastr.error(error.data);
  });
})
```

If i remove the part with the `$q`it works well.
Does any of you had problems with async function in viewRender callback ?

Thanks and have a great day !

ps. the `beforeSendStatus()` function only changes the icons for a spinner.

Comment: can u share code of beforeSendStatus()?

Comment: how is this related to fullCalendar code? Is this example inside the "viewRender" callback? Normally fullCalendar would refresh the list of events automatically when the view is changed, assuming you have defined the event list as a URL or function. I think we need a bit more context about how the calendar is set up.

Comment: How do you populate the Calendar?

Answer (score 0):

what is your Calendar object ? is it https://fullcalendar.io/ ?

> Be carefull if you mixed jquery code with angular; the mix does not
>   work well. Way better to add a global variable and use ng-class to
>   update your call.

I suggest to use an angular ui component such as : http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/

Comment: it is indeed fullCalendar, I know i'm not suppose to mix angular and jquery, but it works well in the others calendar.

Comment: have you tried:  Calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvents', data.data); Calendar.fullCalendar('rerenderEvents') ?

Comment: It is not a problem with adding the event,

Answer (score 0):

First of all I believe you could use [eventSources](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/eventSources/) for multiple even sources.

If you still want to add events 'manually' use [addEventSource](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/addEventSource/) function.

Also for loader you can use fullCalendar's [loading](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/loading/) callback.